# swift: ios13 status bar setting error occurs in SideMenu library

Tags: swift

I introduced SideMenu in CocoaPods, but an error occurs in the ios13 part of the status bar.But I don't know the correct code.
Would you please teach me?

```
var statusBarFrame: CGRect {
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            // How to do for iOS 13??
        } else {
            return UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is the error? Which line is causing the error?

Comment: The problem was that xcode was not updated. Since it has already been updated, the error cannot be confirmed.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

statusBarFrame has been deprecated in iOS 13,

for iOS 13 you can use this

```
var statusBarFrame: CGRect {
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
     return UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.windowScene!.statusBarManager!.statusBarFrame
    } else {
        return UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame
    }
}
```